# Rails Compare values inside ActiveRecord Relations

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

this is a real hair-puller. I've got a junction table that I need to query for 2 different entries, then update the junction table if the values are not there already.

Essentially I have this:

```
master_actors = [#<Actor2role actorId: 13176, dogTag: 45917, roleId: 1, position: 3>, #<Actor2role actorId: 65471, dogTag: 45917, roleId: 291075, position: 1>]

slave_actors = [#<Actor2role actorId: 11123, dogTag: 5384, roleId: 44, position: 5>, #<Actor2role actorId: 65471, dogTag: 5384, roleId: 291075, position: 0>, #<Actor2role actorId: 66652, dogTag: 5384, roleId: 291073, position: 2>]
```

I need to compare the contents of each one of those records and if there are entries in slave_actors not present in master_actors I need insert them.

What I can't figure out is how to compare the contents of those 2 activeRecord relationship objects. Regular array methods like `.include?` don't seem to work. Nor does `master_actors.attributes == slave_actors.attributes` because I get an error saying that the attributes method does not exist for an activeRecord relationship.

Basically I'm really stumped.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried checking if the intersection (`ary1 & ary2`) is empty ?

**EDIT** : As mentioned in the comments below, since there is elements in `master_actors` that can be absent from `slave_actors`, the difference (`ary1 - ary2`) was the right answer

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with intersection (looking up docs on google right now). Could you be so kind as to provide an example?

Comment: The solution I'm looking at now is creating a new array from the difference between both, deleting the entries for slave and inserting the values of that new array with the master ID.

Comment: Mathematically speaking, the intersection of two sets is a set composed by only the elements presents in both base sets. So, taking for granted the fact that there cannot be elements in `master_actors` that are absent from `slave_actors`, I think it should do the trick. See [Array#&](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-26) for more on the topic.

Comment: Actually, there *can* be elements in master_actors that are absent from slave_actors. That's why I went with the difference operator and that did the trick. If you want to change your answer to using the difference operator I can mark it as accepted. And thanks a lot for the help. Your mention of intersection allowed me to find the difference operator which ultimately worked in this case.

Comment: I edited the post. Don't care much about the points, but I think others might find this post more easily if is is marked as resolved

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you. But people seem to be very touchy about this whole accepting answers, that's why I mention it.

Answer (score 0):

how about master_actors.to_a.should eq(slave_actors.to_a) - working for me